# Regresión polinómica en Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Tengo un conjunto de puntos con sus respectivas coordenadas (x,y), las coordenadas en "x" de los puntos están en un array y las de "y" también. Lo que quiero realizar es el ajuste de un polinomio que pase por los puntos, minimizando la distancia a cada uno de ellos. El problema es que desconozco el grado del polinomio a utilizar. Hay alguna forma de realizarlo? Adjunto imagen como ejemplo de los puntos con la regresión lineal a los mismos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función [`numpy.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) puede encontrar los coeficientes del polinomio que ajuste a los datos, pero debes decirle el grado del polinomio.

Observa que cuanto mayor el grado, mejor será en general el ajuste a los datos concretos de tus observaciones, pero más "rara" será la gráfica y más "salvajemente" oscilará fuera de los puntos que no han sido observados.

A modo de ejemplo, usando tus mismos puntos, el siguiente código calcula los polinomios de ajuste de grado 1 (lineal), 2, 3, 4 y 5. Para cada uno se muestra en la leyenda de la gráfica cuál es el error de ajuste (el residuo) y verás que es menor a medida que aumentas el grado, pero yo dudaría mucho a la hora de decir que la de grado 5 es la que mejor se ajusta, pues aunque minimice el error para los puntos de que dispone, produce oscilaciones raras fuera de esos puntos.

```
% matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Tus datos
x = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1.5,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,5])
y = np.array([3,4,5,3,5,4,2,3,5,3,4,1,2,3])

# Calcular ajustes para diferentes grados
sols = {}
for grado in range(1,6):
  z = np.polyfit(x, y, grado, full=True)
  sols[grado] = z

# Pintar datos
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

# Pintar curvas de ajuste
xp = np.linspace(0, 5.2, 100)
for grado, sol in sols.items():
  coefs, error, *_ = sol
  p = np.poly1d(coefs)
  plt.plot(xp, p(xp), "-", label="Gr: %s. Error %.3f" % (grado, error) )
plt.legend()
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, si quisiera añadir la ecuación de la curva que realiza el ajuste como leyenda, de que manera podría obtener los coeficientes de la misma?

Comment: @Agu1997 En el código anterior estarían en el array `coefs`, (que es el primer elemento de la tupla que te retorna `np.polyfits()`).